# Excel Power Query Split Column by Number of Characters into rows but not duplicate values in a another column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a column of data (Request) that I have to split by number of characters 499 into rows. I have another column that has the number of items for that row (Items completed) that I need every subsequent row created from the split to display null or 0 instead of duplicating the value.

Table 1 is original data
Table 2 is table after the split
Table 3 is intended output with 0 or null on the split row

Removing duplicates removes the entire row but need the qualify removing the duplicates in the column based on the Ref ID since i need to be able to count the items completed without over inflating the numbers in the grand total

Tried removing duplicates but it removes the entire row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way in powerquery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=   Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(_, {{"Request", Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(499)}}), "Request"),
    b = Table.RemoveColumns(a,{"Items Completed"})
    in  Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(b) & {{a[Items Completed]{0}}}  ,Table.ColumnNames(b)&{"Items Completed"}), type table }}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Difference(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Grouped Rows", "data"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),{"Name"}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", ColumnsToExpand,ColumnsToExpand)
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Sample to tack onto existing code found in home...advanced editor...

existing code from home...advanced editor...:

```
 #"Something" = blah blah,
 #"SomethingSomething" = blah blah
 in #"SomethingSomething"
```

appended code from home...advanced editor...

```
 #"Something" = blah blah,
 #"SomethingSomething" = blah blah,
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"SomethingSomething" , {"Name"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=   Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(_, {{"Request", Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(499)}}), "Request"),
    b = Table.RemoveColumns(a,{"Items Completed"})
    in  Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(b) & {{a[Items Completed]{0}}}  ,Table.ColumnNames(b)&{"Items Completed"}), type table }}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Difference(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Grouped Rows", "data"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),{"Name"}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", ColumnsToExpand,ColumnsToExpand)
in #"Expanded data"
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this if the source is a query? This table has a lot of applied steps to get to the final table and was wondering if this could be just added to perform the steps you mentioned.

Comment: Eliminate my first step. Use the name of your last step in place of Source in my 2nd step